# Add triple conditional in CASE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a update clause with CASE clause like:

```
UPDATE [D]
                    SET
                       [DesignTypeGuid] = (CASE
                                         WHEN([D].[DesignNumber] < @CurrentContractedDesignNumber)
                                         THEN @BDTypeGuid
                                         ELSE @COTypeGuid
                                      END)
```

My question is how can I add a third conditional, I mean I also want to do is

`[D].[DesignNumber] = @CurrentContractedDesignNumber THEN @CDTypeGuid`

is it possible to merge this to this to existing case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
SET [DesignTypeGuid] = (CASE WHEN [D].[DesignNumber] < @CurrentContractedDesignNumber
                             THEN @BDTypeGuid
                             WHEN [D].[DesignNumber] = @CurrentContractedDesignNumber
                             THEN @CDTypeGuid
                             ELSE @COTypeGuid
                         END)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add  another when

```
UPDATE [D]
SET  [DesignTypeGuid] = (CASE
                WHEN [D].[DesignNumber] < @CurrentContractedDesignNumber
                       THEN @BDTypeGuid
                WHEN [D].[DesignNumber] = @CurrentContractedDesignNumber T
                    HEN @CDTypeGuid
                                   ELSE @COTypeGuid
                                  END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add other `WHEN . .` in `CASE` expression  :

```
(CASE WHEN [D].[DesignNumber] < @CurrentContractedDesignNumber
      THEN @BDTypeGuid
      WHEN [D].[DesignNumber] = @CurrentContractedDesignNumber
      THEN @CDTypeGuid                                   
      ELSE @COTypeGuid
 END)
```